# Azure + Cosmos DB :

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I use Azure and Cosmos DB to store some information, but I have some issues with a new collection I have created.

I always go such kind of error message :

> Failed to update document 5b83e5297dfa952bb4036fa6:
>   {"code":400,"body":"Command update failed: query in command must
>   target a single shard key."}

The collection name is "item" and I try to store some images URLs. So, I first try to add the following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b83e5297dfa952bb4036fa6"),
    "imageURL" : "https://www.tendance-parfums.com/media/resized/460/600/baseline-1/bgcolor-255-255-255/constrainonly-1/defaultimage-/keepaspectratio-1/keepframe-/mode-outer_resize/media/catalog/product/c/h/chanel-n5-eau-de-parfum-vaporisateur-y_2.jpg"
}
```

Notice that the `_id` is created automatically.

So, I don't know why the Azure portal is always giving some errors!

Some details, the collection use the default parameters (Unlimited size), I use `imageURL` as shard key, 15000 as throughput and `item` as collection id.

Any idea?

PS: Another question is that it is looking for a `shard key` when creating the collection, but for now I only have this field `imageURL`, but I'm not sure it is suitable?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code, including where you're getting an error. As written, it's unclear exactly what your issue is. Also, it's unclear whether you're using the SQL (DocumentDB native) API or the MongoDB API. Likely MongoDB API since you mention shard key. But again, there's really no way to answer without more specific details.

Comment: Also: you mention the *portal* giving errors. So, this has nothing to do with code you've written? That being the case: again, please give specifics of the actions you took, to get an error via the portal.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no code, I use the Azure Portal to insert some documents.Noticed that I have also try to insert the data with Xamarin code, but I also have errors, no way to insert such record !!!

Comment: I can empathize with your frustration, but yelling isn't going to solve any problem. I asked for you to edit your question to provide more specifics (such as the API being used). Also, you should provide details of the type of collection you created (e.g. fixed vs unlimited; and all other details). Without more details, there's literally no way to solve your problem here.

Answer (score 2):

I have find a way to fix it, it seems the shard key cannot be an URL, so I use a another complex one and it work !!!